# Very odd issue, $_SESSIONs not working, and favicon not showing before second refresh?

Tags: php, session

So, i am working on this website:

```
http://www.funkydictionary.com/signup.php
```

And i have run in to a very weird issue that i have not had before, i have a login page, and a signup page so far, server language is PHP, i pass error and success msges via sessions, so, when a user tries to log in, or register, a success or failure $_SESSION is set.

And he is redirected to the signup page where his error/success will be shown.

Now for some odd reason, sessions cannot be set, and i noticed that the favicon is not displayed either, until the browser is refreshed ?

When this has happend, everything works fine, but if the browser is clossed and thereby all sessions unset, the samme issue occurs?

I am guessing this has something to do with the server configs?

Any help is appreciated

EDIT 1:

This is included at the top of everypage:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == 1) {

    $error_message = "";
    $success_message = "";

    $now = time(); // checking the time now when home page starts

    if($now > $_SESSION['expire'])
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();

        global $loggedIn;
        $loggedIn = null;

        $error_message = 'Your session has expired, please login again.<br />';

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['error'] = $error_message;

        died($success_message, $error_message, '/login.php');
    }
    else {

    global $loggedIn;
    $loggedIn = 1;  
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT 2:

When/How do sessions expire?

Well on login i set a session ['start'] = time(); and ['expire'] = start + 60*60

here is the code

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

    $_SESSION['start'] = time();// taking now logged in time
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60) ; // ending a session in 30     minutes from the starting time

    global $loggedIn;
    $loggedIn = 1;

    $success_message = 'You have logged in as ' . $row['username'];
    died($success_message, $error_message, '/login.php');
```

Comment: Please show us some code. We have nothing to go on to help with the `sessions` if we can't see the PHP.

Comment: Did you start the session on every page that uses it?  Does the session cookie get set properly?

Comment: Yes session is set on everypage, it has something to do with the favicon not showing aswell, i do not think it is a session issue

Comment: first thing to check.. have you started the session on every age which uses it? aka `session_start();`

Comment: When/how do you set `$_SESSION['expire']`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i fixed it, i have no idea what exactly fixed it, but i changed some session_start() input form and session error handeling, favicon seems updated now aswell, as in, the new favicon